# Selecting Values from a Database with a Query in Java and Use them as a Variable and Insert it in another Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, jdbc

So I selected some values from a database table to divide them in little groups and insert it into another table within the database by putting the selected values in an `ArrayList` and taking the size of that `ArrayList` to do the math.

But after I do the math, I'm just left with the variables containing the information I need. But, I cant put them into the other table because they're not the same things that I selected in the beginning. They're just numbers now. I really need to insert those variables into the other table but when I do, I get foreign key constraint fails error and I think that's because the variable is not a foreign key anymore but just a number. I don't know if there is a solution but it would help me allot. Here is my code:

```
private void spelersVerdelenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             

String comboBoxValue = jComboBoxDeelnemer.getSelectedItem().toString();
String spelerRonde1 = "SELECT lid, toernooi FROM deelnemer where     toernooi LIKE " + comboBoxValue ; 

ArrayList<String> dlnmrs = new ArrayList<>();
try {

  PreparedStatement pstat = con.prepareStatement(spelerRonde1);
  ResultSet rs = pstat.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {

        dlnmrs.add(rs.getString("lid"));
        for (int i = 0; i < dlnmrs.size(); i++) {
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e);
}

verdeelTafels(1, dlnmrs.size()); 

private void verdeelTafels(int ronde, int aantalDeelnemers) {

System.out.println(aantalDeelnemers);

int aantalTafels = (int) aantalDeelnemers / AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;
int restSpelerPerRonde = aantalDeelnemers % AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;

if (aantalDeelnemers == (AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL * 2)) {
    aantalTafels = 1;
    restSpelerPerRonde = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < aantalTafels; i++) {
    int maxSpelersPerTafel = AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;
    if (i == aantalTafels - 1) {
        maxSpelersPerTafel += restSpelerPerRonde;
    }
    System.out.println("Tafel " + (i + 1) + " heeft " + maxSpelersPerTafel + " deelnemers.");

    //spelersDoorlopen

    for (int j = 0; j < maxSpelersPerTafel; j++) {

  String query = "insert into spelerPerTafel (lid,tafel,ronde) select lcode,tfcode,rcode from lid,tafel,ronde ";
  try{ 
         PreparedStatement pstat = con.prepareStatement(query);

         pstat.execute(query);
      }
  catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e);
        System.out.println(e);
      } 

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show your table definitions?

Comment: This sql statement `insert into spelerPerTafel (lid,tafel,ronde) select lcode,tfcode,rcode from lid,tafel,ronde`  isn't well formed. Are you getting the information to insert from some other table? In that case you need to name it. Otherwise you need to use `VALUES(val, val, ...)`

Comment: table lid has allot oft columns: lcode is the only one we need here
table tafel has the columns tfcode,maxAaantalSpeler,minAantalSpeler
table ronde has the columns rcode,AantalRonde,tijdstip,toernooi
table spelerPerTafel has the columns lid,tafel,ronde 
foreign key lid references lcode from lid
foreign key tafel references tfcode from tafel
foreign key ronde references rcode from ronde

Comment: Ozan,  OK, but your problem relates to fk constraints, so not knowing the table definitions makes clear answers hard.

Comment: ow and adding the values like you showed gives me foreign key constraint error canot update child row etc because the variables do not contain the foreign keys I need. they're just numbers

Answer (score 0):

- try

  String query = "insert into tableA select * from tableB where XXX";
- using where condition can implement to divide the tableB